# XCode - Valor da posição do array não é exibido

Tags: array, objective-c, xcode

Tenho um array com 30 posições e em cada posição do array tenho vários objectos tipo: NumProcesso, Nome, Idade, Sexo, DataNascimento.

Gostaria de mostrar todos esses objectos de cada posição em uma só linha utilizando o **NSLog**, mas não quero fazer a concatenação.

[image: Demonstração]
[image: Demonstração]

Se eu utilizar isso:

```
NSLog(@"Conteúdos no array:  %@", [processosArray objectAtIndex:i]);
```

O resultado será: `Conteúdos no array: 0x8cb1da0`

Comment: O que você quer fazer afinal, não entendi sua duvida, qual o problema com o array?

Comment: Se entendi bem você não quer usar `NSLog(@"Conteúdo na posição %i: %@", i, [processosArray objectAtIndex:i]);`?? _Onde está o problema com Array?_

Comment: O problema do array é que ele não mostra os conteúdos que estão nas posições . Exemplo, se eu utilizar isso NSLog(@"Conteúdo na posição %i: %@", i, [processosArray objectAtIndex:i]); Resultado será: posição x: 0x8cb1da0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, 
Seu problema é simples, quando você faz [processosArray objectAtIndex:i]  você esta pegando um objeto do tipo PesquisaProcessosObj e teu NSLog apenas esta mostrando o endereço de memória dele.

Para mostrar alguma coisa interna desse objeto tem que fazer um cast, algo como:

```
PesquisaProcessosObj *processo = [processosArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog("teu log %@", processo.Idade);
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Obrigado, fiz isso e funciona. O contador muda mas os dados são sempre os mesmos, ele vai sempre buscar o mesmo objecto.                                              for (i =0; i< [processosValidar.processosArray count]; i++)
  {
 PesquisaProcessosObj *processo = [processosValidar.processosArray objectAtIndex:i];
  NSLog(@"Info: %@, %@ %@", processo.Nome,processo.Sexo, processo.Idade);
        }

Comment: Tenta ver por debug, se o problema agora não é teu array, talvez todos os itens do array sejam o mesmo.

Comment: Todos os itens do array eram os mesmos porque eu estava utilizar string dentro do array. Para resolver o problema tive que utilizar um array de arrays.